# Is there a way to see all VIM keybindings?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I wish to personalize a bit my vimrc with my own keybindings without accidentally overwriting originals ones.

So I wish to see *all*  keybindings, and not only the ones I mapped with :map .

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
:help index
```

will show you every default key-bindings.

```
:map
```

will show you every custom mapping.

```
:map <leader>
```

will show you every custom `<leader>` mapping.

```
:verbose nmap
```

will show you every custom normal mode mapping and where they are defined.